# Python: List index out of range inside while/for loop

Tags: python, list, concatenation, indexoutofrangeexception

I want to make a Tribonacci sequence. (Every new item is a summation of previous three items from that list.) But it shows list index out of range error whenever I use a while/for loop. Can anybody figure out what is wrong with this code?

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    count = 0
    newlist = []
    while (len(newlist)<=n):
        newitem = signature[count]+signature[count+1]+signature[count+2]
        newlist.append(newitem)
        count = count+1
    print signature + newlist
tribonacci([1,1,1], 5)
```

In this above code, my expected output is [1,1,1,3,5,9,17,31]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vasanth\Desktop\sample.py", line 9, in <module>
tribonacci([1,1,1], 5)
File "C:\Users\Vasanth\Desktop\sample.py", line 5, in tribonacci
newitem = signature[count]+signature[count+1]+signature[count+2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You're not posting the traceback so this is speculative, but I bet `signature` contains less than three items when you start.

Comment: You update count, yet you never actually append items to `signature`, which you use to calculate `newitem`, though that's prolly not what you meant to do.

Comment: @tripleee it does contains three items, cf the snippet's last line.

Comment: the way you use count provokes the failure. As soon as count is 4 or above, you'll be out of range in signature ...you have to handle it another way ///

Comment: @tripleee I'm not the OP. But the traceback is actually useless here, the problem is _very_ obvious <g>

Comment: If you are writing new code, you definitely should be thinking seriously about targeting Python 3. The end-of-life for Python 2 was pushed back, but the original EOL date was just a few months from now.

Comment: @A.Joly the error will actually happen as soon as `count` is greater than zero.

Comment: I think I'm getting @A.Joly's point. I'll try to rectify it. :)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you're right ... the OP has to append to `signature` instead of `newlist` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reduce this to a MCVE:

```
signature = [1, 1, 1]
count = 0
while True:
    newitem = signature[count] + signature[count+1] + signature[count+2]
    count = count+1
```

On the first iteration, `count` is `0` so the "problem" line will effectiveley be:

```
    newitem = signature[0] + signature[1] + signature[2]
```

since `signature` is a 3 items list, this is ok. Now on the second iteration, `count` is `1` so this line will effectively become:

```
    newitem = signature[1] + signature[2] + signature[3]
```

Since `signature` is only 3 items long, there's no `signature[3]` object - your Index is OutOfRange.

Answer (score 3):

After the first iteration you've incremented count to 1, but have not updated `signature` in any way. It holds 3 items, so `count + 2` will try to index the list beyond its boundaries.

Instead you could just sum the last 3 items of a list you append new results to:

```
In [20]: def tribonacci(signature, n):
    ...:     result = list(signature)
    ...:     for _ in range(n):
    ...:         result.append(sum(result[-3:]))
    ...:     return result
```

or, if using Python 3 and hoping to create a generator:

```
In [34]: from collections import deque
    ...: 
    ...: def tribonacci(signature, n):
    ...:     state = deque(signature, maxlen=3)
    ...:     yield from state
    ...:     
    ...:     for _ in range(n):
    ...:         next_value = sum(state)
    ...:         yield next_value
    ...:         state.append(next_value)
    ...: 

In [35]: tribonacci([1,1,1], 5)
Out[35]: <generator object tribonacci at 0x7f6ae11ef990>

In [36]: list(_)
Out[36]: [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31]
```

Comment: Nice, although I'd probably do `result = list(signature)` so `signature` could be a tuple. That `deque` version's a very nice idea.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

```
def tri(original_sig, n):
    sig = original_sig.copy()
    for i in range(n):
        sig.append(sum(sig[i:i+3]))
    return sig
```

---

In your code you are appending the new values to `newlist`, not `signature`. Therefore, after the first iteration your code will attempt to access element 3, which is out of the size of the ist

Answer (score 0):

```
item = [1,1,1]
for i in range(5):
    new = item[i]+item[i+1]+item[i+2]
    item.append(new)
print item
```

Comment: Please try to avoid code only answers by adding some explanation of why your code is the solution to the question. Remember this answer could help someone else in the future and the more information the better.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    count = 0
    newlist = []
    while (len(newlist)<=n):
        newitem = signature[count]+signature[count+1]+signature[count+2]
        newlist.append(newitem)
        count = count+1
        signature.append(newitem)
    print signature
tribonacci([1,1,1], 5)
```

> You were increasing value of counter every time but you were appending new value to signature list.
>   so len of signature remains only 3
>   and when code tried to get signature list's 4th element it thrown this error.

Answer (score 0):

Small modifications of original code in question works well:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    count = 0
    newlist = signature             # change here..
    while (len(newlist)<=(n+3)):    # here..
        newitem = signature[count]+signature[count+1]+signature[count+2]
        newlist.append(newitem)
        count = count+1
    print(newlist)                  # and here.
```

Testing:

```
tribonacci([1,1,1], 5)
tribonacci([2,2,2], 5)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57]
[2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 18, 34, 62, 114]
```

Edit: as mentioned in comments, the original list sent will be modified here.

If original list is to be preserved:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    count = 0
    newlist = signature.copy()      # get a copy of original list
    while (len(newlist)<=(n+3)):    
        newitem = newlist[count]+newlist[count+1]+newlist[count+2] # use newlist rather than signature
        newlist.append(newitem)
        count = count+1
    print(newlist)
```

Testing:

```
a = [1,1,1]
tribonacci(a, 5)
print(a)

b = [2,2,2]
tribonacci(b, 5)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 18, 34, 62, 114]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: It'd be good to mention that `newlist = signature` does not actually create a new list.